# Command to identify running computer

Tags: command-line

Based on development level there are three computers on which I work at.
My personal computer has a different version, and the other two are a development and production servers with similar characteristics but different passwords.

I use some of my code in the three computers, but sometimes I have to adjust settings depending on which computer I'm running the program from.  Is there an environmental variable that will allow me to identify which computer I'm working on, so that I can do this automatically?

The servers are Ubuntu 12.04 and my computer is Kubuntu 14.04.

Thank you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using computers, not _programming_ computers.

Comment: Would the hostname work for you? See: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/hostname.1.html

Comment: @Telastyn Oops. First time here. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `$HOSTNAME`, for example:

```
$ echo $HOSTNAME 
Castle2012
```

may help, as may `$SESSION`, for example:

```
$ echo $SESSION
ubuntu
```

and `$_system_version`, for example:

```
$ echo $_system_version 
14.04
```

Comment: None of those are "unique" to a system...

Comment: True.  I feel that they don't need to be for this users need and in fact this will allow the actual computers to change but still be identifiable this way as (for example) local, remote1 remote2, etc.

Comment: I run Ubuntu 13. Only HOSTNAME has a value.  Neither SESSION nor _system_version has a value.

Answer (score 1):

Probably and a very simple way to differentiating a system from the next one would be the mac address of the first interface.

Each network device present on a system will have a unique mac address, reading the mac address for a device will probably tell you what system you are working on.

For example:

```
$ /sbin/ifconfig p4p1 | grep ether | awk '{print $2}'
b8:ca:3a:c7:e2:e6
```

Using the mac address I can be sure that this is the system I am working on because the mac address of that interface will not match (unless changed on purpose) another system's interfaces mac address.

Comment: Thanks, while not necessarily unique I'm gonna prefer hostname to be more hands-on than the specific MAC address.